# locale.Error: unsupported locale setting WINDOWS 11

Tags: python, ttkbootstrap

I am receiving error since 1 week in python.

Note: Im using W11

I've tried before:

`set LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

`set LC_ALL="C"`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Desktop_brightness_app_github\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    import ttkbootstrap as tb
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ttkbootstrap.widgets import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\widgets.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ttkbootstrap.dialogs import Querybox
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\dialogs\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ttkbootstrap.dialogs.dialogs import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\dialogs\dialogs.py", line 536, in <module>
    class DatePickerDialog:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\dialogs\dialogs.py", line 566, in DatePickerDialog
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, ""))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\locale.py", line 627, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `LC_ALL` is a Linux environment variable specifying both the locale and encoding. Windows doesn't work like this. Both Windows (and Python) are Unicode-only. The locale is specified by the user's settings. There can be different settings for the UI language *and* the locale settings used for formatting and parsing, eg using English UI with German date/number formats

Comment: Basically builded desktop brightness app. Here is github link: https://github.com/Zephyruss1/Desktop-Brightness

Comment: Post a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem in the question itself. If just `ttkbootstrap` results in an error, the library has a bug. Or it was designed to only work on Linux. In that case you'll only be able to run it in WSL

Comment: I think high possibility there is a bug. I worked before with **ttkbootstrap**.  Also thanks to responding back.

Comment: There are [several GH issues, affecting MacOS as well, all ignored](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aisrael-dryer%2Fttkbootstrap+locale&type=discussions). In [this issue](https://github.com/israel-dryer/ttkbootstrap/issues/505) the workaround was to ... just edit the local file

Comment: I solved problem with your guidance. This [link](https://github.com/israel-dryer/ttkbootstrap/issues/505) worked for me. Thanks.